# Nock.js: how do I check for the existence of a header?

Tags: node.js, nock

I am using Nock with Mocha, and want to check that certain headers exist on a request. I don't care about the other headers, and I don't care about the specific content of the headers whose existence I'm checking for. Is there an easy way to do this? `.matchHeader()` passes when the specific header is absent, and `reqheaders` fails unless I specify all the header fields.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`reqheaders`](https://github.com/nock/nock#header-field-names-are-case-insensitive) is the right approach with this.

I'm not sure what issue you came across, but not all the headers need to be supplied. Only the ones that are required for a match.

The other nice feature of `reqheaders` is that the value can be a function returning a boolean. Since you don't care about the actual value of the headers, returning `true` has the effect of matching if the header simply exists.

```
const scope = nock('http://www.example.com', {
  reqheaders: {
    'x-one': () => true,
  }
}).get('/').reply(200, 'match!')


const reqOpts = {
  hostname: 'www.example.com',
  path: '/',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'X-One': 'hello world',
    'X-Two': 'foo bar',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }
}

const req = http.request(reqOpts, res => {
  console.log("##### res status", res.statusCode)

  res.on('data', (chunk) => {
    console.log("##### chunk", chunk.toString())
  })
})

req.end()
scope.done()
```